# How are bookshelf.js events being used?

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I don't understand how to make use of events in bookshelf.js:

https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Events-instance-on

I am missing a list of events, which are already implemented – or – do I have to implement the events on the model myself? And if the latter is the case, *how* is an event being registered on the model?

Maybe someone can point me to an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events are fired automatically by Bookshelf whenever a particular "event" occurs. The way you make use of this is by registering event listeners to do something whenever such an event is fired.

You can actually fire custom events yourself, but I doubt you will need to.

For a list of already available events check the left-hand side navigation bar on the [project's API documentation](https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html) and look for the "EVENTS" header. Example: https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Model-subsection-events

For a more detailed explanation you can check the [Events Guide](https://bookshelfjs.org/tutorial-events.html). It includes examples, but for completeness this is one way to attach an event listener to a model:

```
const User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',

  initialize() {
    this.on('updated', (model) => {
      // This is fired after a model is updated
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow I've missed that.